# Django & Postgres explicit SQL parameters escape

Tags: sql, django, security, postgresql

I need to construct a long SQL request to my database, but I'm not sure how can I escape parameters correctly

How can I explicitly escape parameters in SQL like cursor.execute() does?

Can you also give me an example what exactly this escaping have to do, so I can test it?

Is there any difference if you escape standard SQL request or database function call?

Comment: Okay, I'll bite. **Why** can you not just let `cursor.execute()` handle it?

Comment: because my parameter list is not fixed and I need to make a loop, so I can create a proper SQL request

Comment: select * from function_name(params_count, ARRAY[(param, param, param), (param, param, param), (param, param, param) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to build your parameter list dynamically:

```
sql = "SELECT FROM foo WHERE bar='baz'"
param_list = []
for entry in loop_array:
    sql = sql + "AND " + entry.key + " = %s"
    param_list.append(entry.value)

cursor.execute(sql, param_list)
```

Comment: This looks perfect, but will it work if my SQL is a function call? And how can I test is escaping working properly?

Comment: Sure, it works just es well if you do a SELECT my_function_call(%s, %s). The [Django Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors) confirms that quoting is done appropriately as necessary for your database engine. You can also use tools such as the [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) to check the generated SQL code.

Comment: Last question :) Do %s mean that entry.value is string? What if it is integer? :)

Comment: No, %s is just the placeholder for the parameters. You can also pass ints in the param list.